# Java- How to extract certain String from xml content?

Tags: java

I have a xml response  as a string in my java class main method. (i.e string value= https://pastebin.com/0Z3jUWHh)
I want extract only this "Vehicle has multiple records in the RTO(s)...RTO(s)." from that long xml string, how to do ?

---

**Input:**

```
String a="<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>........"; // https://pastebin.com/0Z3jUWHh
```

**Expected Ouput:**
String expectedOutput="Vehicle has multiple records in the RTO(s) - KARNATAKA(BENGALURU SOUTH  RTO) & KARNATAKA(BENGALURU EAST  RTO) & KARNATAKA(KRISHNARAJAPURAM  RTO). Please contact concerned RTO(s)."

How to do this in java?

I am not able to think about how to start on this

Comment: Please add comments for negative vote!So I knew reason as a new user

Comment: There can be multiple reasons for a -ve vote,
1. Unclear question.
2. Not enough deep dive.
3. Unsupportive artifacts like code pointers missing etc.
Anything you think can provide enough information to the readers to answer your question should be added, in case you miss on these a -ve helps u learn faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future questions you really need to explain the problem better.

You're trying to extract whatever message (not knowing what the message will be) being returned in this XML file without all the superfluous junk so you can utilize it in code, correct?

Normally you'd want to parse the XML using one of Java's XML parsers, but for a quick and dirty solution you can use the SUBSTRING method on your string.

You'll have to use the surrounding text (the text immediately before and after the actual message) to provide substring indexes and hope they never change in future XML return values (bad questions breed bad solutions)...

```
String expectedOutput = a.substring(a.indexOf("detail:") + 7, a.indexOf("});;]]></eval></changes></partial-response>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Better start by reading about xml parsing in java, this will help you swim through the desired output. 
ref: https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

After you have build up the basic understanding go through official documentation here, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28394/adx_j_parser.htm#ADXDK19117

Happy learning.

Comment: Why parse the whole document (or at least up to the string depending on the parser) to get one single string?

Comment: This wasn't the exact answer for OP's question but some pointers to help him realize the solution.